# Php Login / Mysql checking against mysql is not working with SHA512

Tags: php, mysql, sha, sha512

*GOAL: Trying to create a login. The registration page uses this to create the username and password based on input:*

**Register**

```
 <?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="dbname"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Student"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

/* Obliterate bad input */
$secUser = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reguser']);
$badpasses = $_POST['regpass'];
$salt = '~Z`!@#$%I^&*()_-+Q=}]{[\|"><';
$secPass = hash('sha512', $badpasses.$salt);

$sql= "INSERT INTO Student (uname, upass, fname, lname, email, currGrade)                VALUES('$secUser','$secPass','$_POST[regfirst]','$_POST[reglast]','$_POST[regemail]','$_POST[regclassrank]')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
else{
echo "Registered";
}

?>
```

**Login.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="dbname"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Student"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$salt = '~Z`!@#$%I^&*()_-+Q=}]{[\|"><';
$myusername = $_POST['uname']; 
$mypassword = $_POST['upass'];
$mypassword = hash('sha512', $mypassword.$salt);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE uname = '$myusername' AND upass = '$mypassword')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("regduser");
session_register("regdpass"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "$mypassword<br />";
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

The error I get is the `Wrong User or Pass`, but the password when I try to login is:

```
bffbc4f94f40d0cece6774ed9ec792b03ad5362edf768d190913d033c46ad4af4e2cbe1d42134f58da402efb7d3209b7e9b62ff3e81caf6341262b24dd300e9a
```

the password in the database for the user `poop` and password `poop` in the db is:

```
4e4d252a08ac4c35c2917b4fc715fef13bac2b686c7ebc8f8256765bd584a89634df3fa455ed73c1fbec84d442f11d5e064749396dcb1c0f1525f82c1b0ea57a
```

Why are these passwords different?! Can someone help?

Comment: I salute your use of a hash, but as @Pelshoff says below, you have a more basic problem in the form of sql-injection.  However, as long as you know that your current implementation isn't ready to be available to anyone untrusted, it's fine to have sql-injection holes while testing that you would patch (presumably via parameterized queries) before releasing the code to the wild.

Answer (score 2):

Should

```
// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$salt = '~Z`!@#$%I^&*()_-+Q=}]{[\|"><';
$myusername = $_POST['uname']; 
$mypassword = $_POST['upass'];
$mypassword = hash('sha512', $mypassword);
```

not be

```
// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$salt = '~Z`!@#$%I^&*()_-+Q=}]{[\|"><';
$myusername = $_POST['uname']; 
$mypassword = $_POST['upass'];
$mypassword = hash('sha512', $mypassword.$salt);
```

?

You add the salt to the password hash when you register, but you don't add it when you attempt a login.

I also want to strongly urge you not to POST directly into your database queries, but to use the mysql_real_escape for every POST variable that is used in a query. Better still would be to use prepared statements.

Doest that help at all?

Comment: Indeed. There is SQL injection possible. Just have a look at the following xkcd: http://xkcd.com/327/.

Comment: @Shi: The xkcd comic, while both funny and educational, does not apply here. `mysql_query` can only run a single query, so such exploit is not possible ;) (There are other, no less 'interesting', possibilities with this code though). For example, let's say I'll try to login with username `' OR 1--`

Comment: @Mchl As soon as you found a valid username, you can login using `Robert"; --`.

Comment: @Mchl The code checks for `mysql_num_rows() == 1` so without valid username, your suggestion will fail.

Comment: Yeah... he's actually checking for rowcount equal to 1... that saves him from my puny attempt ;P

Answer (score 0):

I do not see where the "salt" is used in your login script. Maybe try the following:

```
$mypassword = hash('sha512', $mypassword . $salt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$_POST['upass'];` variable is empty. Check if your form field is actually called `upass`.

Based on this piece of information:

```
>> $salt = '~Z`!@#$%I^&*()_-+Q=}]{[\|"><';
'~Z`!@#$%I^&*()_-+Q=}]{[\\|"><'

>> hash('sha512', 'poop'.$salt);
'4e4d252a08ac4c35c2917b4fc715fef13bac2b686c7ebc8f8256765bd584a89634df3fa455ed73c1fbec84d442f11d5e064749396dcb1c0f1525f82c1b0ea57a'

>> hash('sha512', ''.$salt);
'bffbc4f94f40d0cece6774ed9ec792b03ad5362edf768d190913d033c46ad4af4e2cbe1d42134f58da402efb7d3209b7e9b62ff3e81caf6341262b24dd300e9a'
```